# Ordinal parameter not bound : 1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting following error when I try to run this query.

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Ordinal parameter not bound : 1

```
@Query("SELECT new com.gymshop.domain.DoanhThuThang(MONTH(orderDetail.order.createDate), sum(orderDetail.price*orderDetail.quantity)) "
                + "FROM OrderDetail orderDetail "
                + "WHERE YEAR(orderDetail.order.createDate)=?1"
                + "GROUP BY MONTH(orderDetail.order.createDate)")
        List<DoanhThuThang> doanhThuTheoThang(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: You need a **space** between the WHERE and GROUP BY clauses.
"...WHERE YEAR(orderDetail.order.createDate) = ?1 GROUP BY.."

Comment: Try dropping the `@Param("id")` part